# Resolving Python dependencies in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, dependencies

I've got a Python project downloaded from Git here. I managed to import it in Eclipse but it's still missing a few things. The following lines are the guilty lines

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import Connection
```

I tried `sudo easy_install bson` and `pymongo` and successfully installed the packages. After restarting Eclipse I've got the same error.

I guess that the build path, if applies to Python too more than Java, is missing a few dependecies.

Since I'm totally new to Python I'd like to know how to fix Python dependencies in Eclipse

Comment: Do you actually get an error when you try to run the code, or are you just referring to a red underline in Eclipse?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054111/pydev-for-eclipse-resolve-python-dependencies-unresolved-imports

Comment: Simply restart Eclipse will not help. You should "rebuild" interpreter in Eclipse for this project.

Comment: I would love to know how to rebuild the interpreter!