# Tweepy installed path

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, tweepy

I have installed **tweepy** as below using windows command prompt.

```
G:\Python27\Scripts>pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-2.3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:c:\docume~1\bishan\locals~1\temp\pip_build_Bishan\tweep
y\setup.py) egg_info for package tweepy

Installing collected packages: tweepy
  Running setup.py install for tweepy

Successfully installed tweepy
Cleaning up...

G:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Now I need to use **tweepy** on my project. But I can't find the installed location of **tweepy** on my PC.

How can I find **tweepy** installed location and import it to my eclipse project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using PyDev? If yes and you have it configured properly, then you don't have to care about physical location of the installed library. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054111/pydev-for-eclipse-resolve-python-dependencies-unresolved-imports) on how to configure PyDev to automatically resolve installed python packages.

But if you really want to know the physical location of the installed library, take a look at Lib/site-packages directory in your Python installation directory. It should be somewhere there.

Comment: Yes i'm using PyDev and just found **tweepy** on `Lib/site-packages directory`. :)